# Do you need to get a new ESTA when your passport is renewed?

Tags: visas, usa, esta, passport-renewals

A bit over a year ago I applied for (and got) an ESTA for travel to the USA, valid for two years. That validity takes the ESTA to pretty close to the end of the passport validity.

I've just renewed my passport a bit early, to avoid problems with having enough passport validity on a different trip. Do I need to also get a new ESTA (for another 2 years starting today), or can I continue to travel on the existing ESTA until that expires, and only need to renew it then? (I am planning to travel to the US before the old ESTA expires)

(If you wish to travel to the US under the Visa Waiver Program, except by land, you need to to apply for an ESTA (Electronic System for Travel Authorization) before you travel.)

Comment: You should really mention what an "ESTA" is.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've found the answer in the [DHS ESTA FAQ](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#UTA2). The bad news is that if you renew your passport, you have to re-apply (and pay again) for a new ESTA:

> **What should I do if the information on my passport has changed?**
>
> If you obtain a new passport or there is a change to your passport information, you must apply for a new travel authorization and pay the associated fees.

There are [a few things](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/WebHelp/ESTA_Screen-Level_Online_Help_1.htm#UTA1) that you can update about your ESTA without having to re-apply, but they aren't passport related. The list is:

- E-mail address
- Telephone number
- Carrier Information
- City where you are boarding
- Address while in the United States