# German entering USA from Mexico after loss of passport?

Tags: usa, passports, esta, mexico, german-citizens

My boyfriend and I visited my family in the USA last year in August. 
Then, after 90 days my boyfriend returned to Germany and stayed there for another 3 months. After that period of time, we met in Mexico to meet my father.

As soon as he arrived, the Mexican Immigration gave him 180 days stay in Mexico. After spending 2 months together, I returned to California to finish school. Our plan was actually for me to go back to Mexico, but instead we decided for him to come here to the US. He has been in Mexico for about 4 months now. He was planning on booking his flight for the 7th of June.

A few days ago, his bag got stolen with his money, ipad and passport inside of it. The problem now is, I read that one cannot enter with the Visa Waiver Program without an electronic passport. Besides that, I'm not sure if he even is allowed to enter the USA from Mexico, since it is part of North America as well.

Now the question is, should we still book the flight? 
Will he even be eligible to enter the US through Mexico?
And how long would it take for the German embassy to make him an eligible passport for entering the USA through the Visa Waiver Program?

Comment: His time in Germany resets his VWP status, and you can absolutely enter under the VWP from Mexico (or Canada).

Comment: What passport does your boyfriend have right now?

Comment: He had a german passport, until it got stolen a few days ago.. with his mexican immigration ticket inside of it. Now he has no passport at all

Comment: He needs to get a new passport and then a new ESTA under visa waiver programme (the old one will not work). He will also need to discuss his exit arrangements with the Mexicans. He should proceed immediately to the German embassy or consulate in Mexico City to discuss the matter. It may take several weeks to prepare a new passport, I do not know the German system. Once he has the appropriate documents he may enter the USA as a regular visitor.
He cannot use an "emergency passport" to enter the USA, unless it is accompanied with a valid visa (NOT an ESTA).

Answer (score 9):

Your boyfriend will have to apply for a new passport at [his local German mission in Mexico](http://www.mexiko.diplo.de/). The reason being that he is not looking to go back to Germany, and thus does not need a one-off document to get home. Indeed he wants to continue travelling and thus will need a brand new German passport. Once he obtains a new passport [he will have to apply for a brand new ESTA since these are valid only for the passport they were issued for](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/do-you-need-to-get-a-new-esta-when-your-passport-is-renewed). Quoting from the linked Travel SE answer:

> #### What should I do if the information on my passport has changed?
>
> If you obtain a new passport or there is a change to your passport information, you must apply for a new travel authorization and pay the associated fees. See What information can I update? for a full listing of information that can be changed after submission of your application.

The application processing times for a new passport will depend on the mission, and on whether or not his case gets accepted as being an emergency. Once again: getting in contact with the German mission in Mexico should be the first step of this entire procedure.